# date time comparison with > does not work

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two SQL statements:

1) (now i use this)

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM public.user_event
where action_type='1' 
  and ip='17.24.25.18'  
  and date_occured between '2019-11-26  13:20:00' and now()
```

2) (but i need to use this)

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM public.user_event
where action_type='1' 
  and date_occured > '2019-11-26  13:20:00' 
  and ip='17.24.25.18'
```

first query return 11 lines
query 2 return 388.

my observation (about query 2) is that instead of "2019-11-26  13:20:00" it is taken "2019-11-26" and when I replace it really returns the same answer

`date_occured` is of type of `timestamp without time zone`

Comment: In which database? You've tagged both `sql-server` and `postgresql`, which are two different things.

Comment: i use postgresql

Comment: Considering the OP states *"PostgressSQL"* in the title, @Diado , I've taken an "educated" guess and removed the `sql-server` tag.

Comment: For some reason I assumed that was added by SO because it was tagged first, rather than added by the OP. D'oh.

Comment: @Baska . . . You may have `date_occurred` values in the future.  This could occur if timezones were involved.  What is the type of `date_occurred`?

Comment: Why should both queries return same number of rows?

Comment: ``` SELECT count(id) FROM public.user_event
    where action_type='1' and date_occured>'2019-11-26' and ip='17.24.25.18'  ``` return same result like htis ```SELECT count(id) FROM public.user_event
    where action_type='1' and date_occured>'2019-11-26  13:20:00' and ip='17.24.25.18' ```

Comment: why? it is hapend

Comment: date_occured is type of  timestamp_without_time_zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `date_occured` is a `timestamp without time zone` field, you would have to indicate it (otherwise your string would be automatically casted as a `date`):

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM public.user_event
WHERE action_type='1'
and date_occured > to_timestamp('2019-11-26 13:20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp without time zone
    AND ip='17.24.25.18'
```